# Javascript to set css properties grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for an equivalent for `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` for javascript dom. I made a simple grid layout in html and css:

```
<div class="box">
    <div id="box1"><a href="#">box1</a></div>
    <div id="box2"><a href="#">box2</a></div>
    <div id="box3"><a href="#">box3</a></div>
    <div id="box4"><a href="#">box4</a></div>
</div>

.box {
    display: grid;  
    grid-template-columns: 33% auto;
    grid-template-rows: 350px 588px;
}
```

I want to edit the styling for `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` in javascript, but I found out javascript dom doesn't support this property. Is there any other way I can edit the boxes so I can change the size of them?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.style.gridTemplateColumns` to alter the columns and `.style.gridTemplateRows` for the rows:

```js
let a = true
setInterval(() => {
  let box = document.getElementById('box')
  box.style.gridTemplateColumns = a ? "20% auto" : "30% auto"
  box.style.gridTemplateRows = a ? "50px 50px" : "150px 188px"
  a = !a
}, 500)
```

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33% auto;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 188px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box">
  <div id="box1"><a href="#">box1</a></div>
  <div id="box2"><a href="#">box2</a></div>
  <div id="box3"><a href="#">box3</a></div>
  <div id="box4"><a href="#">box4</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do the question mark and the let a = true function for in your code?

Comment: @Duco that's a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It's just making the css swap between those two values based on whether `a` is true of false.

Comment: is there a way I can use variables for the values of gridTemplateColumns and gridTemplateRows?